# managed code in SharePoint 2013 apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Can we write managed code in SharePoint 2013 apps and if yes then in which app: Sharepoint hosted app, Provider hosted app, Azure(Auto Hosted App).

If yes then can someone please tell me how

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Client Side Object Model while creating Apps for SharePoint. You can use MSDN as starting point to find out how to create those

[How to: Create a basic provider-hosted app for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381(v=office.15).aspx)

[How to: Create a basic SharePoint-hosted app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379(v=office.15).aspx)

[How to: Create a cloud-hosted app that includes a custom SharePoint list and content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179936(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint hosted apps support JavaScript client object model and REST. Dot NET client object model is not supported in SharePoint hosted apps. However, Dot NET client object model is supported in cloud hosted apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and what about provider hosted app. Do they support Dot .Net model or  JavaScript client object model and REST

Comment: Yes provider hosted apps support JSOM, rest and managed client object model.